# Home and end keys on USB keyboard recognized as left and right arrow in VirtualBox running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, keyboard-layout, remapping

I have got a Microsoft Comfort Curve 2000 USB keyboard connected to my MacBook Pro. The keyboard layout is standard 104 keys.

When I run Windows 7 in VirtualBox the keyboard gets recognized as Standard PS/2 Keyboard.  For some reason the Home and End keys will not get recognized as Home and End. They get recognized as left arrow and right arrow. I have verified this with the 'SharpKeys' software. Home is mapped to left arrow (E0_4B) and End is mapped to right arrow (E0_4D).

The Home and End keys works fine on the numeric keypad though (the number 7 and 1).

I really want the standard Home and End keys to work in my Windows environment.

Anyone got a clue to how I can solve this?

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong. I was using the DoubleCommand software on my Mac to get PC style Home and End keys. Disabling this in DoubleCommand made the Home and End keys start acting normal in Windows/VirtualBox again.